# Query is updating the RequestOBject to DB in spring Microservices based application

Tags: database, architecture, microservices, sql-insert

Need some clarifications on the best practises that needs to be followed while updating data into the DB in a spring microservices  based webapplication

### Scenario

We have a webapplication, in which when the user sends request from the UI, for processing the request, at the backend the request goes to a microservice and we have to update the request and response objects in a particular table in the database. I wanted to know the right approach for updating the data in the databse. Below are my queries.

- Should we insert the request Object as soon as we receive it in the microservices or
- Should we process the request and after the processing, once we receive the response, should we do a single insert to the database with both request and response Object to avoid multiple DB calls.

Please Advise. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to persist the request and response (if not for auditlog ect...)? Can you provide an example scenario?

Comment: We are persisting the data for tracking and audit purpose.  Also for sending the report back to the UI. we have another endpoint in the same microservice for fetching the report,  hence saving this data will avoid redundancy in processing.

Comment: Then for audit logs you should persist the request as soon as it arrives, then if the response is calculated, update the log entry (request-response pair with some other data) with it. It is due to in case of an error happens during the response processing, at least the request gets logged. We use this method in a critical system (finance). But it is generally a business requirement how you should do it, for us it was not an option to lose requests in case of a critical error. Then you should also define if the logging should be done in the same or separate transaction as the business flow.

Comment: So here I think the problem reduces to the requirement if you want to log requests even if an error happens and no response can be generated